# Cosmos document - Store procedure : Save & Execute button is Grey out

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When I create a Store Procedure on Azure Portal - Cosmos DB
I can't execute this store, it's always disable
. Is it relation to my account role ? or anything else.

Thank
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE - 20-March-2018**

Please see answer from ArTrejo-MSFT Below. It is now possible to update stored procedures in portal as well.

---

I'm able to reproduce this behavior for stored procedures in a partitioned collection inside my Cosmos DB (DocumentDB) account. For a stored procedure inside a non-partitioned collection, these buttons are enabled.

Reason for this being you can't update a stored procedure (or trigger or UDF for that matter) inside a partitioned collection.

If you're looking for an alternate tool, may I suggest that you take a look at [`Cerulean from Cerebrata`](https://cerebrata.com/azure-services/azure-cosmos-db). This tool has support for managing data in Cosmos DB accounts. Full Disclosure: I am part of the team that has built this tool.

Comment: So we dont have anyway to execute Proc with partition enable with azure portal ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. You may want to submit this feedback here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db.

Comment: You can execute Stored Procedures using the Data Explorer blade in the Azure Portal

Comment: It's require partition key value, crazy!. useless.

Answer (score 1):

Editing stored procedures in partitioned collections is supported now (only the body, not the id). Please use Data Explorer to edit any execute stored procedures in the Azure Portal